# Adding an Object to a List

Tags: java

Say there is a list of numbers. What is the difference between adding
 `add(int index, Object x)`

and setting an object to the list
 `set(int index, Object x)`.
 Don't they essentially do the same thing? Aren't both functions just adding the 
`Object x`
 to the specified index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) replaces, [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) pushes everything after index back an index.

Comment: Simple and clear, so the size of the array increases when add is used, and set keeps the size the same. I should have known, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Set override your value at `index` position, add extends your values in array(old values remains) and put new value into `index` position.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

> add(int index, E element)
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation).
>
> set(int index, E element)
> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element
> (optional operation).

So no.  They don't do the same thing.  `add` adds.  `set` replaces an existing element.

If there is no element a the index, set will return an error:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

You could, therefore, try them both:

```
try
{
   list.set(index, obj);
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
{
   list.add(index, obj);
}
```

Try to set, and if it returns that specific error, add instead.